# Meteor: accounts-password

Tags: javascript, meteor, passwords

I'm using accounts-password but I can't locate the user collection. Please help.[image]

[image: After registering, I should see the following]
[image: Instead, I keep getting an empty array without the registration data]
Also, in which file can I find the code for the users collection? In an effort to use best practices, I have separated my code into isClient, isServer, and both but I don't see the code anyway.

When I attempt to register a user in the browser I can't retrieve it using  Meteor.users.find().fetch(); in the console.

Here's the my code:

```
Template.register.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('[name=email]').val();
        var password = $('[name=password]').val();
        Accounts.createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password
        });
        Router.go('home');
    }
});
```

When I attempt to register a user in the browser I can't retrieve user information using Meteor.users.find().fetch(); in the console. 
Registration form code:

```
<template name="register">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form class="register">
        <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email"></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
    </form>
</template>
```

Comment: This is not the usual way of asking question around here, but the collection should available on both the client and the server. You should probably provide more information (in text form, preferably) and describe what you did and what specific problem you encountered.

Comment: @MasterAM...I can't access user information. I've tried Meteor.users.find().fetch() after registering and I still get an empty array.

Comment: Without knowing what you did and an error log, it is difficult to provide a proper answer. The code for that collection and everything that driving it is in the packages that you added (which, for those particular packages, is in the `meteor` repository itself). The packages are bundled with your code when the app is built. You should read more about the `accounts` package and understand what it does and its API. Also, please don't use screenshots where text will do. It makes it more difficult to understand what happened and to reproduce your code. Also, have a look at your server console.

Comment: I'm still trying to get a handle on using this interface and each time I submit a question I'm told something different. You say don't use screenshots, others have told me the opposite. It is not my intention to be difficult but as someone who is new to coding and this platform, I often feel that the experts on here are confusing. Thank you.

Comment: [This guideline](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/268093) should get you started on how to post in a constructive way. Posting your code is a good start. What do you mean by "locate the user collection"? Please describe exactly what you did, what you expected and what was the outcome, in a way that is reproducible. If there are any errors on the client or the server that are relevant, add them as well.

Comment: What I mean by "locate the user collection" is where does it show up in my codebase? I was expecting it to be added to one of my .js files but you've already told me that its in the package's code.

Comment: What I mean by "locate the user collection" is where does it show up in my codebase? I was expecting it to be added to one of my .js files but you've already told me that its in the package's code. I've read the guidelines and I'm just trying to figure out how to best clarify my question. Thank you

Comment: Describe what you did. How did you create the user? What commands did you run? Any error in the browser/server console? Is the user actually logged in? What is the result of `Meteor.userId()`? You can run a mongo shell using `meteor mongo` or a server shell using `meteor shell` in your OS command line to run code on the database or on the server, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meteor create hello
cd hello
meteor
```

=> go to http://localhost:3000

Then the collection is just `Meteor.users`. Try `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` in your console, you should get an empty Array : `[]` => it means it's all set up

Comment: @fabien...I've tried Meteor.users.find().fetch() after registering and I still get an empty array.

Comment: Try to install robomongo : http://robomongo.org/ to check if you exist in the database. (and try to log `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` server side)

Comment: thank you but connecting robomongo is turning out to be an entirely new issue for me. Having trouble with authorization.

Comment: It's all local, you can skip authorization. Only enter `local-meteor`in the Name, `localhost` and `3001` for host and port.

Comment: Thank you...that worked :-) now I can focus on my initial challenge